# Can we add pictures of country flags to country tags?

Tags: feature-request, tags, country-tags

I thought the old money site had pictures of flags on the country codes.

Can we add that back?  I imagine we could create a "fake" sponsor for the tag like the real sponsors for tags on Stackoverflow.

I think that would be fine for advertising, because I don't really want to sell the "united-states" tag and have a coca-cola logo next to it.

Comment: +1 Yes the original SE 1.0 site basicallymoney.com had flags added via custom jQuery & CSS.

Answer (score 2):

...and **done!**

You can now get the flags back using [this UserScript](https://stackapps.com/q/2687) that I wrote. The script can be installed on any browser that supports UserScripts, such as Google Chrome, Mozilla Firefox, Opera, and even Safari (complete details [here](https://stackapps.com/tags/script/info)). Please let me know if you have any feedback / comments / questions.

Comment: Thanks. Nice interim solution, but ideally it should be built in.  Stack Overflow users might not mind installing user scripts, but non-tech Stack sites don't have as many tech-savvy users.

Comment: @ChrisW.Rea: It's not too bad for Chrome users - they need only click the link to install the script. Firefox users with GreaseMonkey installed need only click the link as well. But I see your point - Opera is pretty hard to configure and so is Safari. IE users are out of luck.

Answer (score -3):

Our [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com) site has the ability for organizations to "sponsor" a tag by incorporating a small logo ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android)). But even then, this has become a very limited application, reserved to the trademark owner of that term. Nobody is going to sell the [united-states](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/united-states) tag and place a Coca-Cola logo next to it.

Adding a little flag to the country tag is a cute idea, but the sponsorship feature is not available on other sites, yet. To add a country's flag as part of the tag, you may consider adding a small image to the [Tag Wiki](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/tag-folksonomy-and-tag-synonyms/) that describes the use of the tag.

Comment: Re: *"yet"* ... When is this image-in-the-tag feature going to be available on other sites?  6 to 8 weeks? [;-)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19514#19514)

Comment: @ChrisW.Rea I have not heard anything. I image it would come with the territory when the ad engine goes in place. We've been in no rush to do that.

Comment: Re: *"Adding a little flag to the country tag is a cute idea"* ... actually there is a usability benefit -- it isn't *just* 'cute.'  Also: didn't need a "sponsorship" feature on StackExchange 1.0 to implement it; just CSS + jquery.  CSS alone could do it if tags were classed accordingly.

Comment: @ChrisW.Rea: Turns out your comment inspired me to create something. Please see my answer.